# Getting You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression in Powershell dictionary

Tags: powershell

```
$file = 'test.properties'

$dict = @{}

foreach ($line in Get-Content $file) {
   $words = $line.split('=', 2)
   $dict.Add($words[0].Trim(), $words[1].Trim())
}
```

**test.properties**

```
dbpassword=password
dbdatabase=database
dbuser=username
```

Iam trying to read the propeties file in to dictianry as keys and values like below.

```
$dict = @{dbpassword='password', dbdatabase='database}
```

But when I try to run this code. I am getting You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. error. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55116518/edit) your question and describe some more what you are trying to achieve here. Also, provide a bit of an example of these `.properties` files. It _looks_ like you are trying to get a number of these files and combine all their key/value pairs into one large Hashtable. If that is the case, have you thought of what to do with duplicate keys? Do these files have anything else but key/value pairs in them? (Like  `[Section]`s in `.ini` files)

Comment: Hi @Theo, thank you reply. I edited the post. Could you please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this for a given number of files through `$args` (based on your first code) could be this:

```
# $in is an Array of filenames, so use [string[]], not [string]
$in   = [string[]]$args
$dict = @{}

# get a list of FileInfo objects for files that match the names in the $in variable
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.properties -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $in })

if ($files.Count) {
    $files | ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($line in ($_ | Get-Content)) {
            # check if this is indeed a "key=Value" line
            if ($line -match '.+=.*') {
                # get the key and the value and trim them at the same time
                $key, $value = $line.split('=', 2).Trim()

                # Decide here what to do with duplicates.
                # 1) skip adding new values if the key already exists ('First one wins')
                if (!($dict.ContainsKey($key))) {
                    $dict.Add($key, $value)
                }

                # or
                # 2) overwrite any values for keys that already exist ('Last one wins')
                # $dict[$key] = $value
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "None of the given files exist"
}
```

If you can be absolutely sure of the structure in the given `.properties` file, you can also make use of the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.
Using your last edit where you read in a single file:

```
$file = 'test.properties'
if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
    $dict = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData (Get-Content $file -Raw)
}
else {
    Write-Host "File '$file' does not exist"
}
```

The error message you got came I think from the line `foreach ($line in Get-Content $file) {..}`. There you should have put the `Get-Content` part in between brackets like so:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content $file)) {..}
```

Hope this helps